# Elegant way to handle data race caused by passing channel and shared memory

Tags: go, channel, data-race

Here is one case of [Data Race Patterns in Go](https://eng.uber.com/data-race-patterns-in-go/)

> Mixed use of message passing (channels) and shared memory makes code complex and susceptible to data races

```golang
func (f *Future) Start() {
    go func() {
        resp, err := f.f()
        f.resp = resp
        f.err = err        // data race
        f.ch <- struct{}{} // may block forever
    }()
}

func (f *Future) Wait(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case <-f.ch:
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        f.err = ctx.Err() // data race
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}
```

Here is one data race for `f.err`, which could be accessed both in `Start` and `Wait`.

Another issue is that `f.ch <- struct{}{}` may block forever when `ctx.Done()` happened before `f.ch <- struct{}{}`.

What is the elegant way to handle it in Golang?

---

The idea comes to my mind first as below, add context to `Start` function

```golang
func (f *Future) Wait(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case <-f.ch:
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        f.err = ctx.Err()
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}

func (f *Future) StartWithContext(ctx context.Context) {
    go func() {
        resp, err := f.f()

        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return
        default:
            f.resp = resp
            f.err = err
            f.ch <- struct{}{}
        }
    }()
}
```

We want to know if something missing in my solution? or is there a better solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is still data race in the second code snippet. It is possible for `StartWithContext` to fall to `default` case first, and then `Wait` falling into the `ctx.Done()` case.

You have a shared memory problem, and the most obvious way to deal with it is with a mutex. Also note that you are using `f.ch` as a done-channel, so:

```
type Future struct {
   sync.Mutex
   ...
}


func (f *Future) Start() {
    go func() {
        resp, err := f.f()
        f.Lock()
        f.resp = resp
        f.err = err 
        f.Unlock()
        close(f.ch)
    }()
}

func (f *Future) Wait(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case <-f.ch:
        return nil
    case <-ctx.Done():
        f.Lock()
        f.err = ctx.Err()
        f.Unlock()
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the channel to send the error to the waiter.

Change Future to:

```
 type Future struct {
       ch chan error
       // other fields as before
 }
```

Send the error in Start:

```
func (f *Future) Start() {
    go func() {
        resp, err := f.f()
        f.resp = resp
        f.ch <- err
    }()
}
```

Receive the error in Wait:

```
func (f *Future) Wait(ctx context.Context) error {
    select {
    case err := <-f.ch:
        return err
    case <-ctx.Done():
        f.err = ctx.Err()
        return ctx.Err()
    }
}
```

Create a buffered channel to prevent the goroutine in Start from blocking forever when the context is canceled.

```
  f.ch = make(chan error, 1)
```